# How to add a "presenter's name" graphic to Camtasia that appears in from the right

Tags: animation, screen-casting

I want to have a graphic or animation that pops in on the lower right hand side of the screen that says the presenter's names, stays there for a few seconds then moves back off screen to the right. Like what you see on the news when they switch to a reporter in the field, their name appears below, then it disappears.

Can Camtasia do this with its own tools or do you have to use external programs?
In either event, how do you do this in Camtasia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term you're looking for is 'lower third'. [Here](http://blogs.techsmith.com/tips-how-tos/creating-lower-thirds-in-camtasia-for-mac/)'s a tutorial from the software publisher on how to do that.